# Get one directory above current directory in node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there anyway to get the directory above `__dirname`?

```
/opt/node/ <-- Here is my server.js
/opt <-- I need a path to this directory from my node app.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

console.log( path.resolve(__dirname + '/..') );

Comment: Not working, Result: /Library/WebServer/Documents/myApp/backend../uploads